# Two methods (one synchronized the other not) and two threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

If one method of an object is synchronized and the other isn't, can two different threads run them on the same time? I know that when a method is marked synchronized the intrinsic lock has to be acquired, but the second method isn't synchronized, does it matter? Or maybe if one thread acquired the lock, all of the methods cannot be entered?

Comment: Why don't you try it? Why don't you read [the tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)?

Comment: Depends on what type of lock you acquire. Object level or class level.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Two threads can execute those two methods simultaneously. Thread can get lock on synchronized method, but lock is not necessary to execute non-synchronized method.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure both methods can run concurrently on the same object, because the one which is `synchronized` will only make use of *intrinsic lock* of that object & acquire it but as non-synchronized method won't make use of the lock, they both can run concurrently. I came across the same scenario & found the about statement correct. See the below example for more clarity:

```
class LockTest {

    // Sync Method. Will acquire the lock
    public synchronized void meth1() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                + " is executing method1.");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); // to show some processing, Won't release the
                                // lock
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out
                .println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " ended method1.");
    }

    // No lock is required in this method
    public void meth2() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);// to let meth1 execute first & acquire the lock
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                + " is executing method2.");
        System.out
                .println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " ended method2.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final LockTest oracle = new LockTest();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                oracle.meth1();

            }
        }, "BigThread");

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                oracle.meth2();

            }
        }, "SmallThread");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }
}
```

The above code produces output as:

```
BigThread is executing method1.
SmallThread is executing method2.
SmallThread ended method2.
BigThread ended method1.
```

The output shows that `method2` executed while `method1` was also executing concurrently on same object `oracle`.